# Importing .ui in pyqt?

Tags: python, pyqt4

I tried compiling my .ui file via this:

```
pyuic4 gui.ui > gui.py
```

then I tried importing it, but I get:

```
ImportError: cannot import name GUI
```

I tried plenty of tutorials but none of them were helpful, they were all linux.

Is there a way I could modify my `gui.py` and use it like a normal program?

EDIT:

Figured it out!

much easier then I thought

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui, uic

form_class = uic.loadUiType("gui.ui")[0]                 # Load the UI

class MyWindowClass(QtGui.QMainWindow, form_class):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtGui.QMainWindow.__init__(self, parent)
        self.setupUi(self)

app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
myWindow = MyWindowClass(None)
myWindow.show()
app.exec_()
```

Answer (score 0):

If your want to run directly your ui form without subclassing it you can use '-x' parameter with uic;

```
pyuic4 -x gui.ui -o gui.py
```